# Which denominations are considered mainstream in the UK?

Tags: denomination-survey, united-kingdom

Wikipedia lists these denominations as "[mainline protestant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainline_Protestant)" churches in the United States:

- American Baptists
- Disciples of Christ
- Congregationalists / United Church of Christ
- Episcopalians
- Lutherans
- Methodists
- Presbyterians

However in the UK some of those denominations don't exist; I've always understood the *British* mainstream protestant denominations to be:

- Anglican
- Baptist
- Methodist
- United Reformed Church (The Congregationalists and Presbyterians merged a few decades ago to form this denomination).

Does such a definitive list exist anywhere? Is there a way in which some denominations are "officially recognised" in the UK while others aren't?

Comment: This sounds like a list question.  Furthermore, as @DJClayworth points out, 'mainstream' is a very subjective word. I have to VtC as not-constructive.

Comment: The "official recognition" part could be answered definitively, but the rest is subjective.

Comment: The reason I ask is that clearly there is an objective way of determining US mainstream denominations otherwise the WP article wouldn't exist. The "is there an equivalent for the UK" can surely be answered objectively, even if that answer is a straight no with a bit of reasoning

Comment: That's a huge assumption that because Wikipedia makes a list of something it can be defined objectively. As a longtime Wikipedia editor I assure you that is not the case. In fact, in the first four sentences of that article two contradictory lists are presented.

Comment: Maybe I should have posed this question on the WP talk page first :)

Comment: There's a difference between "mainline" and "mainstream". The largest U.S. denomination is the Southern Baptist Convention, and while they are not considered mainline, by sheer numbers they are in the mainstream of American Protestantism.

Comment: @BruceAlderman That's a useful distinction, thanks. The WP article suggests the terms are synonymous but the more I look into this the less plausible that seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *definitive* list of "mainstream" denominations in the UK - indeed the term is largely subjective - but there are a number of official and semi-official ways in which denominations are recognised.

[The NHS Data Dictionary](http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/data_dictionary/attributes/r/red/religious_or_other_belief_system_affiliation_code_de.asp?shownav=1), based on the international Systematized Nomenclature of Medicine Clinical Terms (SNOMED CT), lists some 80 possible values for Christian religious affiliation - but since this is an international list it is not specific to Britain.

Some denominations self-identify as being mainstream; the [URC website](http://www.urc.org.uk/about/about_us) says:

> Although one of the smaller mainstream denominations, the United
>   Reformed Church plays a dynamic and challenging part in the British
>   Christian community.

Wikipedia provides a [comprehensive list of denominations in the UK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aDenominations_of_the_United_Kingdom), categorised into 12 groups (including "interchurch" - ie pan-denominational groups, and Catholicism) but does not indicate which are "mainstream". The twelve groups are:

```
Interchurch
Anglican
Baptist
Catholic
Holiness & Pietist
Lutheran
Methodist & Wesleyan
New Church Movement
Orthodox
Penticostal
Presbyterian & Reformed
Other
```

The Methodist Church website contains a [basic introduction to Christian denominations](http://www.methodist.org.uk/index.cfm?fuseaction=opentogod.content&cmid=2079) which contains some links to some other useful resources. The [World Council of Churches lists 11 member churches that are based in the UK](http://www.oikoumene.org/en/member-churches/regions/europe/united-kingdom.html) while [Churches Together in Britain and Ireland lists several more member churches](http://www.ctbi.org.uk/24/). Since none of these lists are an exact match for one another it is fairly clear that no definitive list exists, but that lots of denominations are "recognised" by some larger organisations.

What constitutes "official" could also be somewhat subjective. It is well known that the Church of England is *the* officially established church in England. The Church of Scotland, Church in Wales and Church of Ireland are not, however, officially established. (The Church of Scotland is an unusual case where some official documentation implies the church is officially established, but the church themselves disclaim this.) ([Source: good old Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_religion#United_Kingdom))

Nevertheless there have been a number of Acts of Parliament relating to individual denominations; this does not of course make them official state churches, but does at least show that they are recognised by the state. Examples include:

- Protestant Religion and Presbyterian Church Act 1707
- Methodist Church Union Act 1929 / Methodist Church Act 1939 / Methodist Church Funds Act 1960 / Methodist Church Act 1976
- Salvation Army Act 1931 / Salvation Army Property Trust Act 1934

Answer (score 4):

This 2007 report entitled [Churchgoing in the UK](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/shared/bsp/hi/pdfs/03_04_07_tearfundchurch.pdf) has a vast array of demographic data on churchgoers in the UK. It even differentiates between regular churchgoers and those who just state affiliation.

For example, among regular churchgoers surveyed, the denominational breakdown is:

- Church of England 31%
- Roman Catholic 29%
- Church of Scotland/Presbyterian 9%
- Methodist 6%
- Baptist 4%
- Pentecostal/New churches 7%
- Other 7%
- Non-trinitarian 3%

All these are defined in the report (especially Appendix 1 Figure 10). This should answer mainstream as in "most common." Mainline is defined as a specific doctrinal stance in the Wikipedia article you link, so denominations on that list would be "mainline Protestant" there too. Though some don't exist there, I think there aren't any that exist there that aren't here/in that master list.

Answer (score 0):

'Mainstream' is not a word with a clear definition, so there is never going to be a definitive list of such things. You can always make arguments for including/excluding different groups. You have made an obvious omission: you've only listed *English* denominations, although you talked about British ones. If you want to include all UK mainstream denominations you should certiaily include the Scottish ones, especially the Church of Scotland (and assuming you count the  Episcopal Church of Scotland as Anglican for your purposes), and also Northern Irish ones.

Apart from that the list you've made is a pretty good one, and I can't think of others with obvious cases to include them. The others listed in the US list have very small presences in the UK. You might also consider that Baptists come in different flavours.

In answer to your second question, the only form of official recognition is the special privileges granted to the Church of England as the state church. These days these are largely ceremonial.

Comment: He didn't talk about Britain. He talked about the UK. Northern Ireland is not part of Britain (and, indeed, has a very different religious profile to Britain), but is part of the UK.

Comment: "I've always understood the British mainstream protestant denominations to be...". "British" is the correct adjective for something that is part of the UK.

Comment: Thanks for the comments on English/British. I'm tempted to edit the question but don't want to make a nonsense of your answer! On the official recognition thing, I understand the Methodist church was founded by act of Parliament (but that of course doesn't make it *the* official church, just *an* official church)

Comment: Methodists were not founded by act of parliament. They were a breakaway group from the Church of England.

Comment: To say a little more, there *are* Acts relating to the Methodist churches, but these are private rather than public Acts - they give legal effect to church unions, transfer of property, etc., but don't amount to establishment. Just like private Acts that reorganize corporations (like HSBC in 2002) without nationalizing them.

Comment: On the British/English point, the Churches Together website lists the Churches of Scotland, Wales and Ireland under "Anglican": http://www.ctbi.org.uk/24/

Comment: The *Episcopal* Church of Scotland, plus the Church of Ireland and Church of Wales, are Anglican. The Church of Scotland, and the United Free Church of Scotland, are not. Look under Reformed Churches, further down the page. (Yes, it's confusing).

Comment: @DJClayworth. And that's The Church **in** Wales, just to be different.